# CSS Align wrapper to the top+bottom of the screen

Tags: html, css

Im trying to align the wrapper class to the top and bottom of the screen so when the user scrolls up/down the body background NEVER shows or leaves a gap.

The HTML and portions of the CSS are shown below;

**CSS**

```
body{
    font: 14px/18px 'Nunito', sans-serif Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;  /* Normal text font */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:url('../img/bgs/bg-1.jpg'); /* Actual background */

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-position: center top;
    background-attachment: fixed;   
    margin:0px;         
}
#wrapper 
{
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    height:100%;
    height: auto !important;
    background: white;

}
```

**HTML**

```
   <body>
            <div id="wrapper">

                    <header id="header">
                           more html + content
                    </header>

                    <div id="content">


                            <div class="default_page">

                                   more html + content

                            </div>

                    </div>
            </div>



    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space you see is a margin, collapsing to the body margin. To prevent this you can simply add `overflow: hidden` to both wrapper and footer, or set paddings (top and bottom respectively) to them.